# Listen to same result from different Android Fragments

Tags: android

There are 2 Fragments 
I'm calling a service from Fragment 1. I have a ResultReceiver in Fragment 1 which listens to the result and **onReceiveResult** will call **method1()**.

I want a ResultReceiver in Fragment 2 to listen to the **same response** but **onReceiveResult** will be calling **method2()**

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify an interface:

```
interface Receiver {
    void onResult();
}
```

Have your two Fragments implement this interface. Fragment1's implementation simply calls method1(), and Fragment2's implementation simply calls method2():

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements Receiver {
    // Remember to register and remove the receiver (e.g. in onAttach and onDetach respectively).
    private MyReceiver mBroadcast = new MyReceiver(this);
    public void onResult() {
        this.method1();
    }
}

public class Fragment2 extends Fragment implements Receiver {
    // Remember to register and remove the receiver (e.g. in onAttach and onDetach respectively).
    private MyReceiver mBroadcast = new MyReceiver(this);
    public void onResult() {
        this.method2();
    }
}
```

Then specify the BroadcastReceiver as a standalone (or inner static) class such that both Fragment1 and Fragment2 will be able to instantiate it:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private Receiver mFragment;
    public MyReceiver(Receiver fragment) {
        mFragment = fragment;
    }

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals(YOUR_ACTION) {
            mFragment.onResult();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. Tried this implementation however only methods in Fragment gets called for now. Fragment 2 replaces part of Fragment 1 only. Wonder if this has anything to do with that! Thanks anyways.

Comment: *only methods in Fragment 1 get called for now

Comment: Did you remember to register the the receiver in Fragment2? If you provide code, I may be able to assist you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can receive results in two different fragments simultaneously.
But there are many ways to achieve this..
1.
I believe the easiest way will be to use object reference.. 
There are two possibilities.. Either create a static method in Fragment 2 and call it from fragment 1 from  onReceiveResult(). Or Create an object of Fragment 2 in fragment 1 and from fragment 2 , assign that it is the same as the instance created by fragment1. Then just call 
object_of_frgament2.method2() from the onReceiveResult() of fragment 1.

2.
 Using interface.Create a custom interface and make the Fragment 2 implement the interface and create an instance of the interface in Fragment 1.
and within onReceiveResult() of Fragment1 you can call the interface method.

While implementing the interface, you can get the result in fragment 2 in the interface method.
Just call method2() from the function....

3.Using Broadcast Receiver.. 
Create a custom broadcast receiver and make all the fragments/activities which need the results to listen to it. and within onReceiveResult() of Fragment1 just broadcast the result..

I believe there are still other ways to do it..

Comment: Thanks for your time! Out of all options I guess option 2 suites best for my requirement. +1 for options given

Answer (score 1):

just pass into your service two different ResultReceiver's ... If the service is already started calling  startService(Intent) again just makes you call  onStartCommand(...) and then you can set  your resultReciever each time.  So you can keep an array of resultreciever's if you want.

saying that, i would never do it this way.  Research Java Observer pattern.  Java has a default implementation of the Observer pattern.  [Here is a link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Observer.html)

Comment: Thanks for your time. +1 for the "Observer" pattern.